# "Local variable referenced before assignment" warning when "else" loop missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, pycharm

I have the following code:

```
def readTweet():
    tweets = open("tweets.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    counter = 0
    coordinates = []

    try:
        line = tweets.readline()    

        if line != "":      
            lineList = line.split()    
        else:       # <----- This statement
            return 0

        for word in lineList:
            phrase = word.strip("[],.?!#")      
            if counter == 0 or counter == 1:
                coordinates.append(float(phrase))
            counter = counter + 1

    except IOError:
        print("Input error, not a number.")
```

My problem is that when I remove `else` statement `else: return 0`, I get a warning saying

`Local variable 'lineList' might be referenced before assignment`

If I were to print such as `print(coordinates)`, I get the same output, regardless if the `else` statement is present or not. My question is, why is Python giving me this warning?

Comment: What if `line == ''`?

Comment: If `line == ""` the following `for` would be executed but `lineList` wasn't set.

Comment: If you removed the else, what would happen if `line == ""`?

Comment: You need to initialize your `lineList` before the try statement, because on case `line` is empty, `lineList` will not be set for the loop.

Comment: *Python* isn't. Your linter is.

Comment: Which linter are you using? I am looking for a linter which could alert on this kind of errors.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is correct.

In the line

```
        for word in lineList:
```

you could access the `linelist` var before it receives any value.
However, it is known to Python as a local variable as it exists at the left side of a `=` in the local scope.

Consider this simplier example:

```
a = 1

def foo():
    print(a)
    a = 2

foo()
```

In this code, `a` is a local variable in the `foo` function's scope and it is being accessed in `print()` call before it gets any value.